# Switch statement for pressed keys in AHK v2?

Tags: switch-statement, autohotkey

I’m new to AutoHotKey. I’m trying to understand syntax for a switch block. Say, I want to assign some different functions for the time when I press ‘a’ and ‘b’ on my keyboard. For instance, ‘a’ key shows a msg box saying, “you pressed A” and for ‘b’ it just shows “now you pressed B”. how can I do this? I would appreciate it, if someone could help me with the code block.

P.S. I already looked at AHK's documentation page, sadly I could not understand a thing.